# Positivity of a specific linear combination of a quadratic and a cosine function

Tags: calculus, inequality

I would like to prove that there exists $\varepsilon,\alpha >0$ such that the following holds:

$F_{\varepsilon} (x)  := 3x^2 -1   + (1+\varepsilon) \cos (\sqrt{6(1+\varepsilon)} \, x) \geq \alpha    \   \ , \    \    \forall x\in \mathbb R $.

A numerical computation with Mathematica gives that this is true for example with $\varepsilon = 0.1$ and $\alpha = \frac \varepsilon 4 = 0.025$.

The simple inequality $\cos(x) \geq 1 - \frac{x^2}{2}$ gives $F_\varepsilon (x) \geq \varepsilon - 3 (\varepsilon^2+ 2\varepsilon) x^2$ and so does not help.